# Abirir un archivo de Excel desde un servidor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo un botón en el cual me abre un archivo de excel, con `Process.Start("ruta");` pongo la ruta del servidor `\\server\etc\etc`, y funciona en mi localhost, pero al momento de subir la app Web al servidor (por medio de IIS), no me trae nada, solo hace un `AutoPostBack`  , solo se que la solucion podria estar relacionado con el `Server.MapPath()` pero no tengo mucha idea de usarlo... Agradesco su ayuda por favor

Answer (score 1):

Veo tu problema, tu quieres que cuando el usuario, de click en un link, se abra la aplicación (Excel) en tu caso, ya con el documento cargado.

Te recomendaría leer un poco de [Cliente-Servidor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc450447(v=vs.71).aspx), para que puedas, entender que procesos se ejecutan del lado del cliente y cuales de lado del servidor.

```
var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    Excel.Visible = true;
    Excel.Workbooks.Open("teste.xlsx");
```

Te explico como funciona, este es un script en JavaScript, hay un documento llama teste.xlsx en el mismo lugar donde esta el .html .aspx .php, etc... que se ejecutando en ese momento. lo que va a hacer es que el Excel del lado del cliente va a abrir el archivo y lo va a mostrar. esto tiene sus limitantes, ya que algunos Browser no ejecutan sentencias ActiveX, pero en IE si funciona.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

`Server.MapPath()`, te obtiene la ruta de donde se encuentra actualmente tu aplicación, entonces tu necesitas completar esa ruta, colocando dentro del paréntesis la ubicación del archivo que quieres obtener, ejemplo:
Supongamos que dentro de nuestro proyecto, tenemos una carpeta llamada Content y dentro nuestro archivo de Excel, seria algo así la instrucción:

```
Server.MapPath("~/Content/archivo.xls")
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: osea en la carpeta content de mi proyecto se guardara  los archivos?

Comment: Así es, ya sea guardarlo o leerlo,
en tu caso como lo vas a guardar solo necesitas asignarle un nombre al archivo (si serán muchos archivos a guardar, ponlos con nombre diferente, si no te los va a sobre-escribir).

Comment: Una pregunta? Cual es la idea de abrir un archivo desde el servidor web con process.start?

Comment: @ctm002 hay una gran diferencia, ya que el abrir un archivo desde un servidor web, te puede ayudar de manera interna a tu aplicación, es decir si necesitas escribir datos en el y generar un log de errores por ejemplo, o leer una plantilla html para el envió de un correo, en cambio, process.start ejecuta un proceso para abrir una aplicación.

Comment: Recuerda que tienes que instalar office  en el servidor web. Y eso no creo que este bien ya que son procesos independientes.